# persistence.xml not found during maven testing

Tags: java, testing, maven-2, jpa, automated-tests

I'm trying to load test data into a test DB during a maven build for integration testing. persistence.xml is being copied to `target/test-classes/META-INF/` correctly, but I get this exception when the test is run.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named aimDatabase

It looks like it's not finding or loading persistence.xml.

Answer (score 16):

Just solved the same problem with a Maven/Eclipse based JPA project.

I had my META-INF directory under `src/main/java` with the concequence that it was not copied to the target directory before the test phase.

Moving this directory to `src/main/resources` solved the problem and ensured that the `META-INF/persistence.xml` file was present in `target/classes` when the tests were run.

I *think* that the JPA facet put my `META-INF/persistence.xml` file in `src/main/java`, which turned out to be the root of my problem.

Comment: +1: Thanks Jhumble, I've spent the better part of the day figuring out why it works in Eclipse, but not in Maven.  This was it!

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Maven2, and I had forgotten to add this dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your persistence.xml located in scr/test/resources? Cause I was facing similar problems.

Everything is working fine as long as my **persistence.xml** is located in **src/main/resources**.

If I move **persistence.xml** to **src/test/resources** nothing works anymore.

The only helpful but sad answer is here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-427

Seems like it is not possible right now for unclear reasons. :-(

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-427

Answer (score 2):

If this is on windows, you can use sysinternal's procmon to find out if it's checking the right path.

Just filter by path -> contains -> persistence.xml.  Procmon will pick up any attempts to open a file named persistenc.xml, and you can check to see the path or paths that get tried.

See here for more detail on procmon: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it wasn't that it couldn't find the persistence.xml file, but that it couldn't find the provider specified in the XML.

Ensure that you have the correct JPA provider dependancies and the correct provider definition in your xml file.

ie. `<provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>`

With maven, I had to install the 2 toplink-essentials jars locally as there were no public repositories that held the dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

we got the same problem, does some tweaking on the project and finaly find following 
problem (more clear error description):
at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.
  PersistenceUnitProcessor.computePURootURL(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:248)

With that information we recalled a primary rule:
NO WHITE SPACES IN PATH NAMES!!!

Try this. Works for us *smile*.
Maybe some day this will be fixed.

Hope this works for you. Good luck.