# Issue with Maven Test with JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jpa

I am trying to build a maven project with various modules like common, server, war. I am keeping the entity beans & other JPA stuffs in common module. Folder structure of the project is as below :::

```
common  
-->src  
---->main  
----->java  
------>com  
------->hello  
-------->domain     --------- Domain Classes  
----->resources  
------>META-INF     --------- persistence.xml    

---->test  
----->java  
------>com  
------->hello
-------->test
--------->domain     --------- Test Classes  
----->resources  
------>META-INF     --------- persistence.xml
```

I have two persistence.xml 
The first one is in src\main\resources\META-INF 
The second one is in src\test\resources\META-INF. 
For executing test cases I will later point the second persistence.xml to memory DB.

In the test class I am trying to create entity manager as below :

```
EntityManager em = (EntityManager) Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test-Persistence").createEntityManager();
```

Test case is getting failed, getting exception as:

```
com.hello.test.domain.TestUser: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Test-Persistence
```

Can anyone one please suggest where I am going wrong.

Regards
Amit Nair

Comment: how do you run your tests? in the command line? or in the eclipse/any other ide? check if it works for command line run: mvn clean install

Comment: I tried running "mvn clean install", "mvn test" & also from IDE(eclipse) but same result.

Comment: please post your persistence.xml contents (in the tests), there might be a problem, that Test-Persistence is not correctly configured, even if config file is present/found

Comment: <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">

Comment: <persistence-unit name="Test-Persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.expense.domain.User</class>
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expensedb" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/><property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/><property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>

Comment: any of the answers here helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591/persistence-xml-not-found-during-maven-testing

Comment: @PeterButkovic thanks for your responses. I could solve the problem. As could be seen in the project structure, I had a various sub modules under the main project. All dependencies were declared in the pom of main project & few were added as dependencies in sub project. There were no runtime exception like ClassNotFound etc.., so I thought the dependencies were correct. Also the Junit error message was like "No Persistence provider for EntityManager", due to which I never felt wrong about depencies. Things started working out as I added all the JPA/Hibernate dependencies in the sub project.